# How can I get the number of columns and rows from 2D list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, row, col

I create a 2D List with n cols and m rows:

```
2DList = [[0 for x in range(cols)] for y in range(rows)]
```

How can I get the number of cols and rows with the simple method?

Comment: if you create the matrix, and you've said that it is nxn of size... I don't see what is you don;t know

Comment: if I have the result of another matrix with different size so to apply an operation in this new matrix this will be a problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.of rows = `len(matrix)`

No.of cols = `len(matrix[0])`, if all the rows are of same size

Comment: Matrix.shape will do

Comment: @sharatpc: that's in case of a *numpy* array, not *vanilla* Python lists.